# know where clicked gridview android

Tags: android, gridview

I am new to android, and I'm currently developing the game memorized. I am using a gridview to display the images. I have an arraylist with pictures (animals) and another arraylist with images (incognita). 
I was able to get when you click on an image I display an animal, and if they get their backs are equal, but if they do not match I can just hide clickeo last picture. achievement esconnder not the first image that was clicked. how I can know that elements of the gridview I pushed ?.

greetings and thanks.

public class Juego3Libre extends Activity implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

```
private ArrayList<Integer> animaleslist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

private ArrayList<Integer> signolist = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

int[] comparar = new int[2];
int[] temporal = new int[2];
int contador=0,contador2=0;

ImageView imgv1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.juego3libre);
    //Acá seteo el nombre del layout
    this.setTitle("JUEGO MEMORICE");

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridView);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context contexto;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        contexto=c;

        //thumbnails are loaded
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.caballo);
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.cerdo);
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.leon);
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.rana);
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.gato);
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.gallo);
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.foca);
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.mono);

        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.caballo);
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.cerdo);
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.leon);
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.rana);
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.gato);
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.gallo);
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.foca);
        animaleslist.add(R.drawable.mono);

        Collections.shuffle(animaleslist);

        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        //
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);
        signolist.add(R.drawable.signointe);

    }

    @Override
    //Number of images to be displayed
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return animaleslist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView imageview;

        if(convertView == null){

            imageview = new ImageView(contexto);
            imageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
            imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageview.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        }else{
            imageview = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        //imageview.setImageResource(animaleslist.get(position));
        imageview.setImageResource(signolist.get(position));
        return imageview;
    }

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ImageView imageview =(ImageView) v;
    //I get the image in the touched position and setup image
    imageview.setImageResource(animaleslist.get(position));

    comparar[contador] = animaleslist.get(position);
    contador=contador+1;

    temporal[contador2] = animaleslist.get(position);
    contador2=contador2+1;

    //Clean the test score
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numeropuntaje);
    tv.setText(" ");

    //I compare the images touched
    while(contador==2){
        if(comparar[0]==comparar[1]){
            //Set text to see if the comparisons are correct
            tv.setText("iguales");
            contador=0;
            contador2=0;
        }
        if(comparar[0]!=comparar[1]){
            //set text to see if compareciones are incorrect
            tv.setText("diferentes");

            //I try to hide the images that are not the same
            imageview.setImageResource(signolist.get(temporal[0]));
            imageview.setImageResource(signolist.get(temporal[1]));

            contador=0;
            contador2=0;
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: I am struggling to understand your question. If you can find some help with your translation, you might get better responses.

Comment: rewrite `I was able to get when you click on an image I display an animal, and if they get their backs are equal, but if they do not match I can just hide clickeo last picture. achievement esconnder not the first image that was clicked. how I can know that elements of the gridview I pushed ?`

Comment: I need develop memory game, with gridview.